# Linker error when trying to compile files to executable in C using Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a linking problem in The Makefile.

```
CC = cc
INCLUDES = include

OBJ_DIR = obj/

#********* LIBFT *************
LIBFT_DIR = libft/
LIBFT_SRC_FILES =   ft_isnum.c
LIBFT_SRC = $(addprefix $(LIBFT_DIR), $(LIBFT_SRC_FILES))
LIBFT_OBJ_FILE = $(LIBFT_SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
LIBFT_OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR),$(LIBFT_OBJ_FILE))

#********* EXEC *************
EXEC_DIR = EXEC/
EXEC_SRC_FILES = ft_exemple.c
EXEC_SRC = $(addprefix $(EXEC_DIR), $(EXEC_SRC_FILES))
EXEC_OBJ_FILES = $(EXEC_SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
EXEC_OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(EXEC_OBJ_FILES))

#********* MAIN *************
MAIN_SRC_FILE = main.c
MAIN_OBJ_FILE = main.o
MAIN_OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(MAIN_OBJ_FILE))


ALL_OBJ =  $(LIBFT_OBJ) $(MAIN_OBJ) $(EXEC_OBJ)
NAME = minishell

all : $(NAME)

$(NAME) : $(OBJ_DIR) $(ALL_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(ALL_OBJ) -o $(NAME)

$(OBJ_DIR) :
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
$(LIBFT_OBJ) : $(LIBFT_SRC)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDES)
$(EXEC_OBJ) : $(EXEC_SRC)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDES)
$(MAIN_OBJ) : $(MAIN_SRC_FILE)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDES)
clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
fclean : clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)
re : clean all
```

All the files compiled to a `.o`. The whole Libft content is compiled but when it comes to linking. I got a problem files when I want to link them I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ft_isalnum", referenced from:
      _ft_exemple in ft_exemple.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [minishell] Error 1
```

So I have:

- A directory **libft** contains one file **ft_isnum.c** has one function `int ft_num(int c)`
- Dir **EXEC** contains one file **ft_exemple.c** has one function `void ft_exemple()` print the return of `ft_isnum()`
- `main.c` contains `main` function that calls `ft_exemple`
- This is how files looks like after compiling:
  [image]

I am sure that all files exist and included to the right headers.
[This](https://github.com/esc-ouni/Minishell) is the link if you want to check.

Comment: In which source file is `ft_strdup` defined (implemented)? If you look at the `make` output, is that source file built into an object file? Is that object file linked with?

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to read [the `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Especially the section about [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). If you set the correct [variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) you can simplify the makefile a bit.

Comment: `ft_strdup` is a c file in libft , its compiled in obj/ directory , the problem is not only with `ft_strdup` its with all **Libft** functions

Comment: The error you show only says that `ft_strdup` is missing. Can you create a simpler example, just one file for the main program and one file for the ft library (effectively creating a [mre]), then copy-paste the full and complete `make` output (copy-pasted as text) to show us?

Comment: i edit my post to show the changes

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i updated my post , can you check please

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i also added an image about how files and directories are after compiling

Comment: You don't show the command line that generates the error.  The object for with `main()` must come before the library, for example.

Comment: Please don't post images to SO.  The error you show is that the linker can't find the symbol `ft_isalnum`.  You say that your source file defines `ft_num`, which is not the same as `ft_isalnum`.  Then you say that your `ft_exemple` function calls `ft_isnum`, which is not the same as _either_ `ft_num` which you claim to define, nor `ft_isalnum` which the linker error claims is missing.  So either your description of your problem is totally wrong, in which case we can't help you solve it, or your functions are all calling different things, in which case your should fix them.